# Divisão em categorias chartjs

Tags: javascript, chartjs

**Situação:** Tenho um gráfico que apresenta a performance do usuário e do grupo de acordo com algumas perguntas que foram respondidas por eles. Cada pergunta pertence a 1 módulo e possui um identificador (lesson).

**Necessidade:** O problema é que não achei nenhuma forma de adicionar essas duas informações: *module* e *lesson* no chartJs.

Tenho o seguinte gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E preciso fazer algo semelhante a isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebam que o segundo relatório esta dividido em Module e Lesson, sendo que a divisão do Module é apresentado o tempo total do usuário e do grupo.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer algo semelhante ou igual a isto?

Comment: Você poderia, por favor, tentar descrever melhor o problema em palavras? É interessante que as questões sejam indexadas pelo Google, de forma a atender a outros programadores com o mesmo problema no futuro. =D

Comment: Editei a pergunta para tentar melhorar... Não sei se consegui deixar claro através das palavras (aceito edições). Acredito que pelas imagens ficou claro.

Comment: @KaranAlvesPereira, Poderia informar especificamente quais itens do gráfico de baixo você gostaria de colocar no gráfico **chart.js**? E o que seriam esse itens? O que representam no gráfico? Qual sua finalidade? Talvez o problema possa ser resolvido de uma forma um pouco diferente, mas para isso é necessário entendermos o problema.

Comment: @Fernando realizei uma edição na pergunta explicando o cenário!!!